# iCloud folder icons sync

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, folders, icon

I have a folder on iCloud Drive. On the Mac, I set the icon of this folder to some custom icon. However when I see this folder from my iPhone, it has the normal blue folder icon, not the custom icon I set for it on the Mac.

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to get iCloud folder custom icons to sync across devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Finder convention, not an iCloud or iOS one.  Any custom icon you assign to a folder in Finder doesn’t sync to iCloud and/or across devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there an official Apple document supporting this?

Comment: It’s actually more of a lack of documentation.  This feature is *only* [referenced in macOS](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-icons-for-files-or-folders-on-mac-mchlp2313/mac); nowhere else.  Plus, you can’t create custom icons on iOS nor on iCloud.

Comment: I see. However apps do get folders with custom icons (on iCloud and iOS), so I guess there is an API for this.

Comment: So just to confirm, if I have two Macs, custom folder icons will NOT sync between them? I have only one Mac so cannot test myself. But if icons are not syncing to iCloud then I guess the custom icons will have to be set individually for each Mac. Am I right? Thanks again!

Comment: I asked Apple support and confirm that icons do not sync. Not even across Macs.

Comment: I have three different Macs (not including mobile devices) and none of my custom icons sync.

Comment: Alright, thanks for checking.